# Change default Maximum Row Height SETTING in Excel 2010+

Tags: excel

I'm using Excel for a variety of tasks. In this case, I'm analyzing CSV files of logs exported from Splunk, which often include stack traces, debugs with large XML documents, etc.

I know the maximum row height is 409 (or 409.5). I know how to select rows and do AutoSize Height.

What I cannot find is how to change the default maximum row height ***setting*** from 409 to 45 (3 lines in the default font size) so I don't have to do "AutoSize Height" every time I open an exported log file.

I thought this setting might be in Options->Advanced but it is not. Is it accessible? If so, where can I find it?

Comment: Maybe this will help: [ExcelRibbon](http://excelribbon.tips.net/T005663_Changing_Default_Row_Height.html)

Comment: Thanks, Brian. I'd seen that article yesterday, and several others like it. Those steps cause Excel to recalculate the default row height when you change fonts. In effect, that's the _minimum_ row height. Even though I'd searched on "maximum row height setting", the articles always mention that 409 (or 409.5) is the maximum, not how to change it, and most questions are about how to get around that limit. Its the same story on MSDN, Technet and the Office support site, and there are no registry keys that appear related. I'm beginning to think the value is just hard-coded someplace!

Comment: I confirmed on MSDN that the maximum row height is not a configurable setting.

Comment: Thanks, Jeffln, for posting that! It would be helpful, if you have the time, to include the link for others who might read this. :-)